# Load different partial views based on the user button action

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an asp.net MVC Application. I am trying to code so that different partial views are loaded based on either of 3 buttons are selected. I am trying my best to follow this post http://forums.asp.net/t/1981845.aspx?Load+different+partial+views+based+on+the+user+action+
but it currently return errors as follows:

An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Web.Mvc.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: The partial view 'UserAccountInfoView' was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:

I would like to use aspx instead of rajor. 
The View is as follows:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#InfoButton').on("click", function() {
            $.get('@Url.Action("InfoAction", "HardwareRequisitionController")', function (data) {
                $( "#myContentView" ).html( data );
            });
            $('#NotesButton').on("click", function() {
                $.get('@Url.Action("NotesAction", "HardwareRequisitionController")', function (data) {
                    $( "#myContentView" ).html( data );
                });
                $('#OrdersButton').on("click", function() {
                    $.get('@Url.Action("OrdersAction", "HardwareRequisitionController")', function (data) {
                        $( "#myContentView" ).html( data );
                    });
                }); 
            });
        });
    });

</script>  
    <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12" id="account-subnavigation">
                        <div class="btn-group" style=" margin-bottom:10px; margin-left:10px;">                          
                            <button class="btn btn-info" style="width:120px" id="InfoButton">Info</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-info" style="width:120px" id="NotesButton">Notes</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-info" style="width:120px" id="ordersButton">Orders</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

               <div class="row" id="myContentView">
                    <% Html.Partial("UserAccountInfoView "); %>
                </div>
```

The HardwareRequisitionController Controller

```
public ActionResult InfoAction()
        {               
            return PartialView("VoIPSubform1");              
        }
        public ActionResult NotesButton()
        {              
            return PartialView("VoIPSubform2");
        }
        public ActionResult OrdersButton()
        {              
            return PartialView("VoIPSubform1");
        }
```

Comment: The error is being throw at `Html.Partial("UserAccountInfoView");` You have not created a view named `UserAccountInfoView.aspx` (if you comment out that line, your code should work fine)

Comment: No, actually I am trying to use <UserAccountView> as just a variable. In its place I want to load either of the partial views: VoIPSubform1 or VoIPSubform2.

Comment: It not a variable. `Html.Partial()` is a method that renders a view - in your case one named `UserAccountInfoView.aspx` which does not exist. Hence the exception! If you don't want to render a view initially, the just delete that line of code in your view

Comment: Hi, Thanks. I did comment, but it does not work. It should. So I am guessing something wrong with the environment. I tried tol include the correct jquery library, but still does not work. 
<script src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/") %>/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js”"></script>

Comment: Do you still get the exception? And what errors are you getting in the browser console?

Comment: Hi, When I click, it just doesn't do anything. I don't get any errors. Is tehre a way I can get to see the errors?

Comment: Just put a `console.log()`of `alert()` statement in the first line of the `.click()` handlers and check its actually being hit.

Comment: Your are getting an error in the console (a 404) - You do not have a controller named `HardwareRequisitionControllerController`!

Comment: Hi, I think its not working because at some places I am using razor syntax instead of aspx    $.get('@Url.Action   let me try to fix this and get back to you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get the error is because `Html.Partial("UserAccountInfoView")` is attempting to render a view named `UserAccountInfoView.aspx` and it does not exist. You need to removed that line from your view.

Next the `$.get()` functions will throw a 404 Not Found error in the browser console because you do not have a controller named `HardwareRequisitionControllerConroller`. You need to modify the `Url.Action()` methods to remove `"Controller"` from the controller name and use the aspx syntax.

```
$.get('<% Url.Action("InfoAction", "HardwareRequisition") %>', function (data) {
  ....
}
```

not

```
$.get('@Url.Action("InfoAction", "HardwareRequisitionController")', function (data) {
```

Comment: Hi, I deleted this line, but still nothing happens.

Comment: Read my answer again. (and you need to change it to the Url.Action to the aspx syntax). You need to learn to debug your scripts!

Comment: Hi, I changed the get function to aspx syntax..Thanks.  But controller name is right

Comment: namespace ServiceDeskForms.Controllers
{
 [HandleError]
 public class HardwareRequisitionController : Controller
 {

Comment: Yes the controller is named `HardwareRequisitionController` which means that you need to use `Url.Action("InfoAction", "HardwareRequisition")` NOT `Url.Action("InfoAction", "HardwareRequisitionController")`. Read my answer again!!

Comment: Yes Sir, you were right. I had to remove the Controller part from the controller name. I saw the error in firebug that the link without the word controller was working. http://localhost/ServiceDeskForms/HardwareRequisitionController/InfoAction does not work http://localhost/ServiceDeskForms/HardwareRequisition/InfoAction works but when I open that link in browser it gives new error  The partial view 'VoIPSubform1' was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:

Comment: Which means you have not created a view named `VoIPSubform1.cshtml`

Answer (score 0):

As Stephon mentioned you don't need `Html.Partial("UserAccountInfoView")` your markup should be like this:

```
<div class="row" id="myContentView">

</div>
```

One more thing: I think the action names aren't correct, they must be: `NotesButton`, `OrdersButton`:

```
...
$('#NotesButton').on("click", function() {  
    $.get('@Url.Action("NotesButton", "HardwareRequisitionController")', function (data) {  
        $( "#myContentView" ).html( data );  
    });  
    $('#OrdersButton').on("click", function() {  
        $.get('@Url.Action("OrdersButton", "HardwareRequisitionController")', function (data) {  
            $( "#myContentView" ).html( data );  
        });  
    });  
});
```